# What is wrong in this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

Which of these is correct "I thought she has it" or "I thought she had it"?

Comment: Nobody can say because you've provided no context. They're both fine but they say different things, so only say the one that means what you intend -- whatever that may be, since you haven't told us.